# Any examples of Pact testing with Kafka in .net

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, pact

We have a project where we are consuming data from a compacted Kafka topic.
The business is keen to use pact to cover integration testing across the suite of microservices.
However as of yet we have been unable to find anyone who has achieved this using .net.
Bearing in mind there is a relatively tight deadline for this is this a path worth pursuing?

Answer (score 0):

Pact .NET currently doesn't support what is known as "message pact", the feature to enable this form of testing.

There's a [PR](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/pull/175) that details a current approach and at least one [branch](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/tree/message-pact) with WIP changes to enable this.

You could consider building the branch of Pact NET and doing a spike in your project to see how far it gets you. The underlying engine supports pact message, it just requires it to be exposed in the Pact .NET lib.